# Using multiple scale_colour_gradient scales for different ranges of the data in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am very new to R so please bear with me if something is not clear in my question.

I have a `data.frame` "protein" with 5 columns, namely;

1.protein_name, 2.protein_FC, 3.protein_pval, 4.mRNA_FC, 5.mRNA_pval and 6.freq.

I am trying to plot a volcano plot with x=log2(protein_FC), y=-log10(protein_pval). Then map the size of the dots to freq and colour to mRNA_FC. This all works fine and here is the code that I have used:

```
ggplot( protein [ which ( protein$freq <= 0.05 ),] , aes( x = log2( protein_FC ) ,
       y = -log10 ( protein_pval ) , size = freq , colour = mRNA_FC , 
       label = paste(protein_name,",",mRNA_pval), alpha=1/1000)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_text( hjust = 0 , vjust = 0 , colour = "black" , size = 2.5 ) + 
  geom_abline( intercept = 1.3 , slope = 0) + 
  scale_colour_gradient(limits=c(-3,3))
```

all is fine till here. But because of the nature of the experiment, data it is quite dense around `mRNA_FC = 0`. There, the default colour scheme that ggplot applies doesnt work very well in distinguishing different points.

I have tried various colour scales by using `low="colour1"` and `high="colour2"`. However I think it will be best to use multiple colour scales over the ranges of `mRNA_FC`, i.e. something like. blue to white for `-3<mRNA<-0.2`, red to white for `-0.2<mRNA_FC<0`, green to white for `0<mRNA_FC<0.2` and black to white for `0.2<mRNA_FC<3`.

But I havent found any way of doing it yet.

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: I do not fully understand your question. An example figure or dataset would be nice, to better understand what is wrong with the default ggplot2 colorscales.

Comment: The default colour scale rounds of the data around mRNA_FC=0, but I want it to show entirely different colour on the two sides of 0. I feel that its showing points very close to 0, say -0.1, 0 and 0.1 with the same colour. Sorry I can not share the data set because its due for publication soon and the owner of the data doesnt want to make it public yet.

Comment: Then what about a discrete colour scale with user defined `breaks`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this type of thing you want to use `scale_gradientn`. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)

x = seq(-0.1, 0.1, len=100)
y = 0:10
dat = expand.grid(x=x, y=y)

ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=x)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c('red', 'yellow', 'cyan', 'blue'),
    values   = c(-0.05,-1e-32,1e-32,0.05),
    breaks   = c(-0.05,-0.005,0.005,0.05),
    rescaler = function(x,...) x,
    oob      = identity)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you John. This is exactly what I wanted. To be honest it took me a while to figure out the best way of using it, as I said in the post my experience in R is 2 weeks old.