# automatic non-equidistant breaks in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I create a simple scatter plot with `ggplot2` and visualise the z-variable with a color:

```
 require(ggplot2)

 data = data.frame(x=runif(1000), y=runif(1000), vis=rf(1000, df1=1, df2=3))
 qplot(x=x, y=y, data=data, color=vis)
```

however, this is of course not very informative since the distribution is heavily skewed:

```
 hist(data$vis)
```

the problem - in my opinion - is the equidistant breaks that creates bins for data that is simply not in the sample.

so here is my question: is there an efficient way of overcoming this problem and creating more breaks where more data is available. or in other words i'm looking for non-linear breaks or non-equidistant braks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** probably something more similar to what you want:

```
breaks <- quantile(data$vis)
qplot(x=x, y=y, data = data, color = vis) + 
     scale_colour_gradientn(breaks = as.vector(breaks), colours = 
     c("grey", "blue", "red"), values = as.vector(breaks), 
     oob = identity, rescaler = function(x,...) x, labels = names(breaks))
```

[image]

**Old answer:** In this case breaks are not what you really want

```
qplot(x=x, y=y, data=data, color=vis) + scale_colour_gradient(breaks = 1:10 * 10)
```

[image]

Considering amount of data we have

```
quantile(data$vis, seq(0, 1, 0.1))
          0%          10%          20%          30%          40% 
9.294095e-07 1.883887e-02 8.059213e-02 1.646752e-01 3.580304e-01 
         50%          60%          70%          80%          90% 
6.055612e-01 9.463869e-01 1.638687e+00 2.686160e+00 5.308239e+00 
        100% 
1.693077e+02
```

so possibly something like

```
qplot(x=x, y=y, data=data, color=vis) + scale_colour_gradient(limits = c(0,5))
```

[image]

would be good, here points > 5 are grey. A more complicated solution, which you maybe wanted in the first place would be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142180/using-multiple-scale-colour-gradient-scales-for-different-ranges-of-the-data-in).

Comment: thanks for your help... that's not quite what i was looking for. i guess: `scale_colour_gradient(breaks=as.matrix(quantile(data$vis))` is closer to my intention since it takes account of the skewness and it works without visual inspection. yet: the colors are not adapted to my breaks strangely...

Comment: @Seb, yes, that is what I meant: here breaks do not work in the way that you need, `1:10*10` was just an example of that. You should combine `as.vector(quantile(data$vis))` with the answer that I mentioned in the end.

Comment: sorry, i have not been around for some days - looks good and i will try it in a minute :) tanks!