# adjust the scale in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [automatic non-equidistant breaks in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132124/automatic-non-equidistant-breaks-in-ggplot2)

I am creating a ggplot2 heat map chart. My Data is as follows:

```
df    

 Date    Value     Desc
1/1/2012 40       Brasil
1/1/2012  90      Argentina
1/1/2012  10      England
1/1/2012   5      China
2/1/2012 40       Brasil
2/1/2012  90      Argentina
2/1/2012  10      England
2/1/2012   24      China
3/1/2012 40       Brasil
3/1/2012  90      Argentina
3/1/2012  10      England
1/1/2012   0      China


ggplot(df, aes(Date, Desc, fill=Value)) + geom_tile(colour="white") + scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="red"")
```

ggplot comes up with its default scale from 10 to 50 etc on the right as legend. How can I manually alter this? Rather than having 10, 15, 20, 60 etc. I like to have lowest to highest with break points?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the `breaks` argument I think. see `?scale_fill_gradient` for a description:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Date, Desc, fill=Value)) + 
  geom_tile(colour="white") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", 
                      high="red", 
                      breaks=seq(min(df$Value), max(df$Value), by=30))
```

Comment: thank you @Justin. One quick question, if the min and max values have many decimal points and I like to to be a number without decimal points.

Comment: @user1471980 take a look at `?round` for your various options.